# Can I ignore application.cfc in subdirectories and only use the one in root

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

It is pretty publicized that an ColdFusion will look up the directory tree from child to parent directories for an application.cfc file.

This allows all cfm files to be "Locked" unless the application.cfc file that is first found allows the processing of the files.

Is there a way to tell ColdFusion to NOT stop at a sub directory and ALWAYS go to the root?

The reason being is that this situation creates a "Back Door" security problem by simply creating a directory somewhere in the file structure and adding an application.cfc file.

The server would never get to the proper application.cfc and thus the security would never be set properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no, there is no way to tell ColdFusion to ALWAYS use application.cfc at the root.

Please secure your web server carefully, upload to outside of webroot, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks.  That was what I figured.  This is one of those "What if we have a developer go bad and tries to make a back door before they are fired" realizations.  I don't think it would ever happen in any other way.

Comment: Only senior developers should be allowed to deploy code to a live server - and *all* changes should be code reviewed by the senior developers before deployment. If you don't trust your senior developers... well, you might as well fire them now.

Answer (score 2):

As Henry says, you can't currently do this with CF. However, this exact feature is one of the handy extra features which [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org) supports.

You can change the default behaviour so it looks in current directly only, or root directly only.

[image: (diagram of railo's application listener settings)]
<sub>(source: [hybridchill.com](https://hybridchill.com/misc/railo.application-listener.png))</sub>

Of course, this is a *performance* feature, not a security one -  you shouldn't be allowing any untrusted source to create rogue Application files!

Comment: Thanks!  Railo seems more and more impressive every day.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to do this in ColdFusion 9 though. ColdFusion 9 will allow you to specify the where to search for Application.cfc files, just like Railo.